# PHP many objects with one Class

Tags: php, oop

I'm very new with PHP and OOP techniques.

So I have no problem creating a object like so:

```
$member1 = new Member('person 1');
```

But is there a way to return a bunch of objects. So that I can iterate through them and put them in the DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Example
{
    public function getPeople()
    {
        $objs = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        {
            $obj[] = new Person('Person ' . ($i + 1));
        }
        return $objs; // returning an array of Person objects
    }
}
```

```
$example = new Example();
foreach($example->getPeople() as $person)
{
    // Do something with $person
}
```

Comment: Can I create a Class, that returns an array of objects?  I want to search for some members, and then display them in the DOM.

Comment: You can create a method that returns an array of objects. Class - code abstraction. Object - instantiation of a class.

Comment: @Gamak:  No, you cannot have a class constructor return a value.

Comment: What I mean to ask is, Can I put a method in a class that returns a bunch of objects?

Comment: @Gamak Sure, you can make it a static method so that it's not related to a specific object but can be called generally.

Comment: Ok Got it! Is there a performance hit for doing this type of thing?

Comment: @Gamak:  For using arrays and objects?  I suppose it would depend on how many objects you're returning.

Comment: So, in procedural, I would just grab all my members, and put them an array.  But in OPP, I need a method which instantiates a member class for all my members.  It seems like more steps, which I worry might be a performance hit.

Comment: @jeroen:  It would be depending on the context, of course. OP should consider that.

Comment: @Gamak No, you can just do `$members = Example::getPeople()`

Comment: @Tim Cooper I agree, I would probably have it in another class as well, but I guess that's personal and depends on the circumstances.

Comment: @Gamak:  It sounds like you're using OOP just for the sake of it, which isn't a good situation to be in.  You should understand why an object oriented model would make sense and how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get objects, one possible way is to use array :-

```
$members = new members( array(...));
// you can assess any member via $members->members[$some_id] 

// class to return list of members
class members ()
{
  public $members = array();
  public function __construct( array $ids)
  {
    foreach ($id as $id)
    {
      $this->members[$id] = new Member($id);
    }
  }
}

class member()
{
  public function __construct($id)
  {
    // any other thing you want to do
  }
}
```